# SQL Server db updating on project build without running update-database (Using EF6 and code first migrations)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using C# and EF6 with code first migrations to update my database but whenever I make a change to a model, add the migration and build the project, it updates the database! I'm not typing in update-database at all.

I've tried going through the controller and debugging the code to see if a database update is explicitly being called anywhere but I can't find anything. I've tried commenting out the AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed flag but that hasn't solved the issue. Interestingly, the nuget console doesn't actually show the seed method being run either (The body of the seed method is commented out but the actual function isn't)

Here are the exact steps I take if anyone wants to try to recreate this issue:

1. Make some change to the model (Delete/ add a column, etc...)
2. In nuget package manager console, type "add-migration "MyMigration"
3. Build the project

Here's my configuration constructor

```
public Configuration()
        {
           AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
           AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
        }
```

Comment: Do you call `Database.SetInitializer` in your DbContext ?

Comment: @Drakkin yeah, it's being called, is that why this is happening?

Comment: can you add this line of code in your answer please

Comment: it looks like that was it! I commented it out and now it's working as I expect. Thanks

Comment: `code: System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DatabaseContext, Configuration>());  `